# ORA-00932: CLOB error only on oracle 11.2.0.4.0

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

we have an java application with jdbc that is using the following sql

```
select DISTINCT S_SQL, NAME, from TBL_SQL where S_SQL  like %s and flag='1'
```

Column S_SQL is CLOB and the sql is working on my environment which has oracle 11.2.0.2.0 also tested on another machine with oracle 12c.
But on client environment it is not working and throws following error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Is this issue with oracle 12.2.0.4.0 and if it is, can you post possible solution for the problem. Only thing that comes to mind is to wrap CLOB with to_char().

Comment: Check my answer with wrapping object. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611392/oracle-fastest-way-to-compare-tables-containing-clob-and-get-diff/43614109#43614109). 
It also works with distinct operator.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz thank you I might consider it as a solution, strange thing is that the sql is not working only for that version of oracle which is commercial

Comment: All version of oracle work in that way. Clob data type can store up to 4gb. Comparing this amount of data will be time consuming.